# How to Parse Select Value from Javascript / Ajax to PHP without Refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from a MYSQL Database.

I want to make the `Select` value go into the `PHP` through `JavaScript / Ajax` but I do not know how to parse the value with the `POST` method.

My Code:
HTML Select:

```
<select id="valueSelectBox" name="valueSelect">
              <option value="defaultPlaceholder">Select Value</option>
              <option class="value1">Value 1</option>
              <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
              <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
              <option value="value4">Value 4</option>

            </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#valueSelectBox').change(function() {
    var valueNum=$(this).val();

  $.get("php/getValue.php?valueNum="+valueNum, function(data){
      $('#show').html(data);

    });
    });
});

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
        include_once('mysql_conn.php');

  $valueNum = $_POST["valueNum"];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `values` WHERE `valueNo` = '"$valueNum"'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<b>Value:</b> " . $row["valueNo"];

    }
} else {
    echo "Value Not Found.";
}
?>
```

But the PHP code `$_POST` ends up being `null`.

Also when I try and test it, the following error occurs:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$valueNum' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/html/php/getValue.php on line 13`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get that data using get method also.
Problem is in your javascript you are passing variable name "valueNum".

This is the line-->
$.get("php/getValue.php?valueNum="+valueNum

But in your php script you are taking $_POST["values"].

This is the line-->
$valueNum = $_POST["values"];

So just change $_POST["values"] to $_GET["valueNum"], it will also work.

Comment: I think he wanted his data to be sent via `POST`

Comment: `POST` or `GET`, either will do. also i changed  `$_POST["values"]` to `$_GET["valueNum"]` but it still did not work.
I will rewrite the javascript if i must.

Comment: Also when I try and test it, the following error occurs: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$valueNum' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/html/php/getValue.php on line 13`

Comment: I changed it to `GET` as well as the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a `GET` request instead of a `POST`.

Use the JQuery [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function and set its `method` parameter to `POST` :

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "php/getValue.php",
  data: { values: valueNum }
})
.done(function(data) {
  $('#show').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is OK, I have found the solution, turns out it was my SQLQuery throwing the error because of the 2 Quotation Marks (" ") as well as (' ') and not the actual GET Method.

**I changed:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `values` WHERE `valueNo` = '"$valueNum"'";
```

**To:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE `courseNo` = '$valueNum'";
```

Thanks anyway Guys!